# Is there a way for sqlite after I get the result it will create into a new database?

Tags: c#, sqlite

I tried to pull-up some data from sqlite database using C#. Is there a way after I get the result it will create into a new database?

Comment: You can create a database using c# given that you have a valid connection and access rights. Did you even try to research this?

Comment: yes, I was trying find a better way to do it.

Comment: How could we know if our suggested way is better if you didn't post what you currently have? Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can [ATTACH](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html) a new database to an existing sqlite session, and use [CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT ...](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html) to make a new table in that database with the results of a query.

For example:

```
$ sqlite3 a.db
sqlite> CREATE TABLE foo(name TEXT);
sqlite> INSERT INTO foo VALUES ('a'), ('b'), ('d');
sqlite> ATTACH DATABASE 'b.db' AS b;
sqlite3> CREATE TABLE b.foo AS SELECT * FROM foo WHERE name < 'c';
```

(Except do that with C# functions not the sqlite3 shell)